# How to fix SQL Server database diagram error "Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal 'dbo' does not exist"?

Tags: sql-server, database-diagram

When attempting to create a database diagram I get the following error:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the database owner for the files setting in the database properties is unassigned (or blank).

To fix this:

- Right click on the database you need to create a diagram for.
- Choose `Files` from the left hand navigation menu of the dialog box.
- Enter `sa` in the `owner` field.
- Click `OK`

This gives the `sa` permission to create files on the server.

src: [SQL SERVER – Fix Error – Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal “dbo” does not exist](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2021/10/21/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-execute-as-the-database-principal-because-the-principal-dbo-does-not-exist/)